# How to retrieve and print the text and image on browser from mysql db using Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

How to retrieve and print the text and image on browser from mysql db using springs..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring-ORM](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html) support to communicate with DB.

Comment: [Basic Example](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html) is here, But don't forget to refer docs

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
[Spring JDBC](http://www.jpalace.org/docs/spring/jdbc.html)